# CSS not displaying in Chrome

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

I am starting to develop a new site using a template of the old, the website displays correctly in IE, Safari and Firefox but Chrome does not seem to display any of the css.

http://volunteershub.co.uk/vmsmain

P.S none of the links work my question is CSS only at this stage. I have tired on Chrome on different machines and clearing the cache.

I have tried clearing the cache, checking all the CSS links and checking the CSS works with the browsers it is currently working with.

Comment: Did you not check the browser console? Says right there, loud & clear: `Mixed Content: The page at 'https://volunteershub.co.uk/vmsmain/' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure stylesheet 'http://www.volunteershub.co.uk/vmsmain/assets/css.responsive.css'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.`

Comment: No I hadn't I am not that familar with Chrome but thank you very much solves the inssue.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Mixed content isn't allowed in Chrome you can fix this by change

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://www.volunteershub.co.uk/vmsmain/assets/main.css" />
```

to

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//www.volunteershub.co.uk/vmsmain/assets/main.css" />
```

when you load the page over https then must get the Style files from https